# Change foreach to do only one call

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a list where I call item foreach of them, that I want to do is use just one call instead of each item: there is my logic

```
List<Embarcaciones> embarcaciones = new List<Embarcaciones>();

foreach (ListItem item in itemsEmbarcaciones)
{
    embarcaciones.Add(new Embarcaciones
    {
        Categoria = idioma == "Espanol" ?
        item["Categoria"] == null ? string.Empty :
                 ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue)(item["Categoria"])).LookupValue
        : item["Categoria_x003a_English"] == null ? string.Empty :
                ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue)(item["Categoria_x003a_English"])).LookupValue,

        Title = item["Title"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Title"].ToString(),
        Imagen = item["Imagen"] == null ? string.Empty : (item["Imagen"] as FieldUrlValue).Url,
        Enlace = item["Enlace"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Enlace"].ToString(),
        Especificaciones = item["Especificaciones"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Especificaciones"].ToString(),
        Specifications = item["Specifications"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Specifications"].ToString()
    });
}

result.Embarcaciones = categoria.Contains("\"") ?

embarcaciones.Where(x => x.Categoria.ToLower().Contains(categoria.ToLower())).ToList() :
embarcaciones.Where(x => x.Categoria.ToLower().Equals(categoria.ToLower())).ToList();
```

How can I change my method to only call one time instead "foreach" method? Regards

Answer (score 4):

You want to use LINQ.

```
List<Embarcaciones> embarcaciones = itemsEmbarcaciones.Select(x => new Embarcaciones() {
    Categoria = (idioma == "Espanol" ? (x["Categoria"] == null ? ... : ...) : ...),
    Title = ...
    ...
}).ToList();
```

But you really shouldn't be using so many nested ternary ifs (true ? "true" : (false ? "true" : "false")).  It becomes really ugly really quick.  But if you do, at the very least, use parenthesis.

Comment: I preder to use a new method to check if null `private string CheckNull(ListItem item)
{
 return item == null ? string.Empty : item.ToString();
}`

Comment: I go one step further and make it an extension method.  The nice thing with extension methods is that since they translate into static calls, you can call extension methods on null values.

Comment: I try it but I received a A NotSupportedException

Answer (score -1):

Replace `foreach(...) embarcaciones.Add(...)`  with `Select(...).ToList()`:

```
var embarcaciones = itemsEmbarcaciones.Select(item => new Embarcaciones
    {
        Categoria = idioma == "Espanol" ?
        item["Categoria"] == null ? string.Empty :
                 ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue)(item["Categoria"])).LookupValue
        : item["Categoria_x003a_English"] == null ? string.Empty :
                ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue)(item["Categoria_x003a_English"])).LookupValue,

        Title = item["Title"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Title"].ToString(),
        Imagen = item["Imagen"] == null ? string.Empty : (item["Imagen"] as FieldUrlValue).Url,
        Enlace = item["Enlace"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Enlace"].ToString(),
        Especificaciones = item["Especificaciones"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Especificaciones"].ToString(),
        Specifications = item["Specifications"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Specifications"].ToString()
    }).ToList();
```

You can also clean up by using the `null coalescing` operators, if you are using C# 6, which is standard in Visual Studio 2015:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

//...

var embarcaciones = itemsEmbarcaciones.Select(item => new Embarcaciones
    {
        Categoria = idioma == "Espanol" 
                       ? (item["Categoria"] as FieldLookupValue)?.LookupValue ?? string.Empty
                       : (item["Categoria_x003a_English"] as FieldLookupValue)?.LookupValue ?? string.Empty,

        Title = item["Title"] as string ?? string.Empty,
        Imagen = (item["Imagen"] as FieldUrlValue)?.Url ?? string.Empty,
        Enlace = item["Enlace"] as string ?? string.Empty,
        Especificaciones = item["Especificaciones"] as string ?? string.Empty,
        Specifications = item["Specifications"] as string ?? string.Empty
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: null coalescing operator supports only in C# 6.0, and your answer is the same as @jeromeyers

Comment: C# 6 isn't standard in Visual Studio 2015! I can use VS2015 with .Net Framework 2.0 for example. Only projects that builded on .Net Framework 4.6 or .Net Core supports C# 6.0

Comment: @MegaTron IDGAF what you've changed your settings to.  C#6 is the default for a new C# project out of the box, which to me is what "standard" means.

Comment: Ok but why do you think that OP has just created a new project and use .Net 4.6?

Comment: Because 4.6 is a year old now, it *replaced* 4.5 and earlier, and there is no tag to say otherwise.

Comment: what is the difference in your approach with using Select and approach of @jeromeyers that answered earlier?

Comment: @RoadieRich `.NET 4.6` did not replace `4.5`, `3.5`, or `2.0`. I still prefer to use `.NET 4.5x` which did replace `4.0` that had some issues.

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN you are right. The answer doesn't make sense. It is like an answer above and tells about specific syntax that probably not used by OP and not helps to solve the problem that was described in question

Comment: @MegaTron if you think it's against the rules to post an answer similar to another, flag it for deletion.  Otherwise, what is your objection?